# What is the meaning of square brackets before unary predictate

Tags: c++, square-bracket, unary-function

I was reading this code on Rosettacode:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Closest-pair_problem#C.2B.2B

And I stumbled upon this strange function inside of `std::copy_if()`

```
std::copy_if(std::begin(yP), std::end(yP), std::back_inserter(yS),
[&minPair, &xM](const point_t& p) {
    return std::abs(xM - p.first) < minPair.first;
});
```

What does `[&minPair, &xM]` before function means?

Why function has no name and no return type? Compiler implicitly guesses that its `bool`?

Comment: The would be the [capture](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) of a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew about lambdas.